# Jenkins Job DSL plugin: How do I create a nested view? Example doesn't work for me

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm in the midst of generating all our views using the Job DSL plugin.

The list views were created without a problem, but now I'm having troubles replacing my nested views.

If I copy & paste the example from https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/nestedView , I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (ViewsGenerator.groovy, line 23) No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild.call() is applicable for argument types: (foobar.jenkins.views.generator.ViewsGenerator$_run_closure1$_closure5) values: [foobar.jenkins.views.generator.ViewsGenerator$_run_closure1$_closure5@4e414e59]
Possible solutions: tail(), wait(), name(), max(), last(), any()
```

Line 23 is

```
  views {
```

If I just use

```
nestedView('ZZZ_project-a') {
}
```

then Jenkins generates the nested view with that name, but of course it's empty!

I must be doing something very basic in a wrong way  :-)  but I can't figure it out! Any ideas?

---

I now tried using the given example directly in a Job DSL generator job (`Use the provided DSL script`), and that works!

What is the difference between my Groovy script and the one in the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of banging my head on the table :-) I finally found the solution.

As usual, the problem is with my software  :-)

I have a helper class called `Views` which reads some XML etc. etc.
And there's a method called `getViews()` in there.
For convenience, I usually import such helper classes with

```
 import static Views.*
```

So, within the Job DSL's `nestedView` there are `views`, and apparently Groovy got confused about what `views` to use, the ones from the Job DSL or my `getViews()`.

I renamed that method to `getAllViews()`, and the problem was solved.

But getting there (I'm by no means a Groovy expert) was a pretty hard experience, since the error message was very cryptic to me.